# How to unit test repository method

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, mocking, moq

I have this method to unit test:

```
public virtual TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }
```

Could someone please tell me how to unit test this?

I'm thinking what I need to test is that Find is called with the correct id?

First I was trying to mock the context `_db` using Moq. Set isn't virtual though so can't use `Verify`.

Could someone please suggest an alternative method of testing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Repository implementation is usually full of calls to ORM API. There is nothing to **unit** test here. You should write an **integration** test instead. Use in memory database like SQLite. Read [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/08/14/testing-with-nhibernate-and-sqlite.aspx) or [this](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing). This way you will cover your mappings, criteria, HQL etc. I know that you are using EF but I think that principle is the same as NHibernate.

Regarding mocking `_db`. There is a very good guideline: [Don't mock types you don't own](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html).

Answer (score 0):

I put a generic repository implementation on github that allows easy testing. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/rcravens/GenericRepository

The repository implementation itself is tested and there is also a fake (in memory) repository implementation that you can inject in to test higher level code.

Bob